# How to install ndarray crate?

Tags: multidimensional-array, rust, rust-cargo

Here are the methods I have tried:

1. run "cargo install ndarray", error: specified package `ndarray v0.15.1` has no binaries
2. download, unzip and run "cargo build", "cargo install --path ." from "https://github.com/rust-ndarray/ndarray", error: specified package `ndarray v0.15.1 (C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\ndarray-master)` has no binaries
3. edit "Cargo.toml" with [dependencies] ndarray = {path = "C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/ndarray-master"}, error: error[E0463]: can't find crate for `ndarray`

BTW, code is here:

```rust
extern crate ndarray;

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Put `ndarray = "*"` in the dependencies in `Cargo.toml`. Just like any other dependency.

Comment: @Jmb Thanks for the response. Yet I haven't installed the crate. Can you help me with the installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to install crates in Rust. You simply declare them in the project's `Cargo.toml` file:

```
[dependencies]
ndarray = "0.15.1"
```

When you then build your project, cargo will download and build the needed crates on-the-fly.
[See more here.](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/guide/dependencies.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response and it works! I thought "cargo install" was something like "pip install" and believed I had to install a library first.

Comment: `cargo install` is for installing executable crates, i.e., crates that are complete programs [like `ripgrep`](https://crates.io/crates/ripgrep). It is not used for adding library crates (like `ndarray`) to a project.